# How do I prove that a normal space is $T_0$?

Tags: general-topology

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Separation_axioms.png

In this diagram, you can see that a normal space is $T_0$.

How do I prove this?

Comment: A normal space is usually defined as $T_1$, which implies $T_0$. How do you define a normal space?

Comment: @Ayman See Brian's answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/536195/what-is-a-necessary-conditions-for-urysohn-metrization-theorem . I don't mean $T_4$ space, that is, i don't assume normal to be $T_1$.

Comment: And as in the link in the post, it's written there normal space without $T_0$ is $T_0$

Comment: I'm aware of the different definitions out there; this is why I'm asking about your definition. The Wikipedia article defines $T_4$ as normal and $T_1$. This implies $T_0$. The diagram doesn't mention the word normal.

Comment: @Ayman It's written in wikipedia: In this diagram, the non-T0 version of a condition is on the left side of the slash, and the T0 version is on the right side. Letters are used for abbreviation as follows: "P" = "perfectly", "C" = "completely", "N" = "normal", and "R" (without a subscript) = "regular". A bullet indicates that there is no special name for a space at that spot. The dash at the bottom indicates no condition.

Comment: So non-$T_0$ version of normal space implies $T_0$, if i understood this sentence correctly.

Comment: @Ayman: In my experience definition of *normal* that does **not** include $T_1$ is more common.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Oh well. It is unfortunate that two opposite usages exist as you explain in [your answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/536205/4583). My first exposure to the separation axioms was via Munkres's book, and he includes $T_1$ in the definition. Perhaps this is why I'm biased. Thanks for your input!

Comment: @Ayman: You’re welcome! I have to admit that I’ve always wondered why he did that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the assumption of T$_1$-ness (or T$_0$-ness), normal spaces need not be T$_0$.  To see this take the trivial topology on any set $X$ of size $\geq 2$.  As the only closed sets are actually clopen it is easy to separate disjoint closed sets by disjoint open sets, and so the space is normal.  This space is also clearly not T$_0$, since the only nonempty open set is the entire space.

---

***Added***

Note that the [Wikipedia article on Separation Axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_axiom#Relationships_between_the_axioms) says the following about the diagram:

> In this diagram, the non-T$_0$ version of a condition is on the left side of the slash, and the T$_0$ version is on the right side. Letters are used for abbreviation as follows: ... "N" = "normal".... A bullet indicates that there is no special name for a space at that spot. The dash at the bottom indicates no condition.

The connection in question in the following:

$$\begin{array}{c}
\text{N/}\bullet \\
\left| \vphantom{\binom 1 1}  \right.\\
-\text{/T}_0
\end{array}$$

An inspection of the entire diagram indicated that the intended meaning is that the left- and right-hand-sides at the top of the line imply the respective properties at the bottom.  (So some un-named property which includes T$_0$-ness (and is implied by T$_4$-ness) in turn implies T$_0$-ness, while the non-T$_0$ normality implies no further condition.)